# Fixing div after scrolling up and keeping it fixed after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having two problems with this example:

1. `fixed_header_bottom` should be fixed underneath of `fixed_header_top` when scrolled up so `fixed_header_middle` disappear gradually when scrolled up, or vice versa. **Actually this works on my pc but for some reason it doesn't on JSFIDDLE!** so I had to raise it too.
2. If I refresh the page when the cursor is at the bottom of the page, `fixed_header_bottom` should be still fixed underneath of `fixed_header_top`. Fails only on Opera browser (12.16), other browsers fine.

[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/6KAdU/4/)

How can I solve the problems?

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $(window).bind("scroll", function (e)
        {
            if (! $('#fixed_header_bottom').hasClass('fixed'))
            {
                if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 300)
                {
                    $('#fixed_placeholder').show();
                    $('#fixed_header_bottom').addClass('fixed');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($(document).scrollTop() < 300)
                {
                    $('#fixed_placeholder').hide();
                    $('#fixed_header_bottom').removeClass('fixed');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#fixed_header_top
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #DD33DD;
    top: 0px;
}
#fixed_header_middle
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #DDDD00;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#fixed_header_bottom, #fixed_placeholder
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #11DD55;
}
#fixed_placeholder
{
    display: none;
}
.fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
#body_block
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fixed_header_top">fixed_header_top</div>
<div id="fixed_header_middle">fixed_header_middle</div>
<div id="fixed_header_bottom">fixed_header_bottom</div>
<div id="fixed_placeholder">Shouldn't see me</div>
<div id="body_block">BEGIN
    <br />
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />Bottom
    <br />
    <br />END
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to your jquery code:

```
if($('#fixed_header_bottom').offset().top<=50) {
      $('#fixed_header_bottom').addClass('fixed');
} else {
      $('#fixed_header_bottom').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KAdU/5/

Note: It makes no sense to have $(document).ready() inside $(window).load()

Comment: Didn't change anything on Opera.

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/6KAdU/5/show/` : Check it out with Opera browser. It still doesn't fix it after page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you can Save last window Scroll Into a Cookie And read it and get this value to set scroll location :)

it is Best Idea 

Or use html sharp Link:

```
<div id="mydiv" ></div>

<a href="#mydiv" >Link To Div by 'mydiv' id </a>
```